# How can I retrieve data from server and update content on a page when user clicks on a link?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am trying to get Express to send back some data that is retrieved from a feed to my view (.hbs) when user clicks on any one of the 3 links on the page.

[Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggkPi.jpg)

The 'not requested' value is the initial value when the page is first loaded.  I want my page to make a trip to the server and fetch data for the feed that is requested by user.

**server.js:**

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.render('home.hbs', {
       pageTitle: 'Feed reader',
       pageHeading: 'Home page',
       contents: _contents
   });
});
```

I can confirm that all the properties in the above object have the expected values.  Ideally, the page will not display any feed contents (or show something like "not requested") when it is first loaded.  Then, when the user clicks on a link, data should be populated in the "tab-content" div (see below).

**home.hbs:**

What would you like to read today?

```
<ul class="nav md-pills nav-justified pills-secondary">
    {{#each contents}}
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#{{name}}">{{name}}</a>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>

<!-- Tab panels -->
<div class="tab-content">

      <!--Panel 1-->
    {{#each contents}}

    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="{{name}}" role="tabpanel">
        <br>
        <p>{{data}}</p>

    </div>
    {{/each}}
     <!--/.Panel 1-->
</div>
```

How can I stay on the same page but be able to update the contents dynamically based on which link is clicked? I am thinking JQuery/AJAX but am at a loss how to use them since I have very limited experience with it.  Another piece of the puzzle, for me, is how do I tell express to handle this, given that I'm not redirecting or rendering a new page.

Appreciate any help or guidance in this regard.

Comment: Could you please share your JSON data here?

Comment: @GibinEalias the JSON data is already the 'contents' in the res.render arguments sent to the home page. It is being sent to the page when I first load it.  The issue here is I would like the data to be updated based on the link being clicked (see image).  Thank you!